# How to write a query that will retrieve the items with sold amount

Tags: oracle

Problem : I have a table which has three columns such as 
item id ,transaction_date,Amount_sold.

I want to have a list of item with Amount sold which are sold today but if the same item was sold yesterday then it should not come in my list.

Comment: Do you want the sum of amounts per item or the individual rows?

Comment: Is transaction_date has time on it or just date?

Comment: To answer to query it would be Sum of amount per item  and transaction_date is date but still oracle takes it a datatime.

Comment: @SujitKumar I updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

Not exists will work here

```
 select item_id, amount_sold 
       from table t
   where transaction_date = trunc(sysdate) 
     and not exists (select 1
                       from table t1
                      where t1.item_id = t.item_id
                          and t1.transaction_date = trunc(sysdate)-1;
```

EDIT based on OP's latest observations :

```
select item_id, SUM(amount_sold) as amount
       from table t
   where trunc(transaction_date) = trunc(sysdate) 
     and not exists (select 1
                       from table t1
                      where t1.item_id = t.item_id
                          and trunc(t1.transaction_date) = trunc(sysdate)-1
 group by item_id;
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `trunc(sysdate) -1 ` in `not exists` ?

Comment: one more note - I think you need to compare   `trunc(transaction_date) `, not `transasction_date` itself  with `trunc(sysdate) ` and `trunc(sysdate) -1` .   Or rewrite condition in both `WHERE`  a bit : for instance,  `... WHERE transaction_date >= trunc(sysdate) and transaction_date < trunc(sysdate) +1 `

Comment: @a1ex07 We don't know if transaction_date has time or just date. I'll ask the OP. I don't want to truncate the column right away if is indexed. Thanks again

Comment: @SujitKumar please post some sample data.